# How do I efficiently checking if a string matches any substring in a collection

Tags: algorithms, strings

I have a collection of substrings

```
"this" "is" "a" "antelope"
```

I need to look at any given string and answer the question "Are any of the given substrings in this string"

So my input string might be

```
"issue"
```

Which would be a match because "is" is a substring of "issue"

My first stab at this, I incorrectly turned my collection of substrings into a trie.  That got me nowhere fast as it answered the inverse "is the input string a substring of the given collection".

Is there some algorithm or data structure I can transform my collection into to efficiently answer this question?  I mean, I could do the simple brute force "check the input against every substring" method, but it seems like there is a better way.

In my given example, I would expect that "antelope" would never be checked because "a" covers every case that antelope would. I may even expect that "is" would remove "this" since every case that "this" would find a match "is" would as well.  So it seems like eliminating longer substrings with shorter ones would yield some better performance.

I'm rambling... Anything I should be looking into?

Comment: Have you looked into standard substring search algorithms (like Boyer-Moore)? You could search for each substring in your collection successively until you reach a match.

Comment: @dirk5959 Sequentially using a single-string matching algorithm would be very inefficient. For example, if the string to be searched doesn't contain "a", it certainly doesn't contain "banana" but you'd look for it anyway.

Comment: Hint: suffix trees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the [Aho-Corasick](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) algorithm is your best bet here. The algorithm is designed to solve the set matching problem (essentially the one you've defined), in which you want to determine which elements of a set of substrings, L, can be found in a longer string, S.

It runs in time $O(n + m + z)$, where $n = \sum \limits_{l \in L} |l|$ (the total combined length of the substrings in $L$), $m$ is the length of S, and $z$ is the number of matches of $L$ in $S$.